# Classe Java para análise de desempenho de meu projeto

Tags: java, desempenho, classes

Estou à procura de uma classe Java ou pacote para me ajudar a fazer uma análise da performance de meu app. Eu preciso de informações, tais como: o tempo de processamento, consumo de memória, uso do processador ... e assim por diante. Eu sei que há algumas ferramentas para fazer isso, mas eu quero incorporar no meu projeto esse tipo de análise. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Olá, Gilliano. Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você está querendo saber de um app *mobile*, *enterprise*, *desktop* ou algum outro tipo específico?

Comment: Olá! Estou querendo saber de um app desktop.

Comment: Tem algum motivo pra você não querer usar [as ferramentas existentes](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-performance-troubleshooti-0)? Porque, ao meu ver, desenvolver algo próprio vai ser extremamente complicado e trabalhoso, além de redundante. Pode também ser específico demais. Por exemplo, se quiser construir algo para o Windows, você pode usar os contadores nativos ([este é um exemplo que usa C# e Java via JNI](http://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2014/03/recording-java-metrics-with-windows.html)) - ainda assim o seu monitoramento será da JVM e não necessariamente do seu código.

Comment: Oi Luiz! Não é que eu não queira sar as ferramentas existentes. Eu quero na verdade é integrá-las ao meu projeto, para que o usuário não tenha que sair do ambiente e executar outro programa, entende?

Answer (score 2):

Ja experimentou o jmeter? para testes javaEE nao tem melhor. Suporta configuração proxy e certificado.

Comment: Dá para integrar o JMeter no projeto para testá-lo durante sua execução no servidor de produção?

Comment: O JMETER é configurado como uma aplicação client, independente de estar local, remoto ou mesmo um site de terceiro... A principio ele "GRAVA" todas as ações que voce executa com ele iniciado, depois reproduz todas as ações que voce executou, seja post, get, redirect ou acesso... e voce determina quantas execuções ele repetirá e quantas vezes executará a repetição. É possivel determinar constantes e variáveis para ele. Para que ele intercepte suas requisições, vc configura-o como um proxy, onde o navegador passa por ele e ele registra toda requisição.